# How to redraw a UIView after an async call is loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` that's an outlet in a `UIViewController`, in the ViewController I make a network call, dispatch to the main queue and pass the downloaded property to the view.  Inside the view I thought I could use a computed property and call `setNeedsDisplay` to redraw the view based on the updated property but this is not happening?

```
class MyViewController {    
  @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyViewType! 

  func asyncCall() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      myView.property = result 
    }
  }
}

class MyViewType: UIView {
  var property: [propertyType] = [] {
    didSet {
      setNeedsDisplay() 
    }
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { 
    //Drawing code using property
  }
}
```

Comment: Classes should begin with a capital letter...

Comment: How are you drawing or laying out `MyViewType`? Is it in a storyboard?

Comment: @AdamPro13 in its `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { }`

Comment: is it a sublass of UIView i see class MyViewType

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes sorry

Comment: Did you tried setting myView.setNeedsDisplay() working or not ???

Comment: you mean calling setNeedsDisplay in the viewController?  yes I did, still isn't redrawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, `setneedsDisplay()` was being called, but I was doing some additional processing on `property` i.e. casting to an `Int` but was using a `lazy var`.  So I moved the `var asInt` declaration inside the `draw` function and it works now.